# How do I validate a username and password in Azure AD?

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, jwt, bearer-token

I want an example code to allow users to login with their username and password in Azure AD. After successfully logging in, I want to get an Access Token

At the moment I have no connection with Azure AD, I hard-coded a user.

```
        // POST api/values
        [HttpPost, Route("login")]
        public IActionResult Login([FromBody] LoginModel user)
        {
            if (user == null)
            {
                return BadRequest("Invalid client request");
            }
            if (user.UserName == "JO3434" && user.Password == "defDDMKJM")
            {
                var secretKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("superSMKLJMKey@345"));
                var signinCredentials = new SigningCredentials(secretKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

                var claims = new List<Claim>
                {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName)
                };
                
                var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                    audience: "http://site.azurewebsites.net",
                    issuer: "http://site.azurewebsites.net",
                    claims: claims,
                    expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60),
                    signingCredentials: signinCredentials
                );

                var results = new
                {
                    token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token),
                    expiration = token.ValidTo
                };
                return Ok(results);
            }
            else
            {
                return Unauthorized();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without connection with Azure AD, you could not validate the user, also I think it is unnecessary to do that, if you get the token with [`AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identity.client.publicclientapplication.acquiretokenbyusernamepassword?view=azure-dotnet) methond, it essentially uses the [Azure AD ROPC flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc), it will validate the user automatically for you, if the user is invalidated, it will give an error `Error validating credentials due to invalid username or password`.

[image]

Comment: +1 vote and accepted as solution.
Thanks to AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword and a bunch of steps I can now Login and get Valid Tokens... Thank you so much Joy.